# JPanel custom background

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, japplet

OK, let's say I have this Image:

> ImageIcon imageBack = new ImageIcon(System.getenv("APPDATA") +
>   "\.my_game\bg.png");

and I have a `JPanel` that I can toggle on and off. How do I get that `JPanel` to use the custom `ImageIcon`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on your requirement you can use one of the solutions from [Background Panel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/12/background-panel/).

Comment: +1 for excelent code, basic stuff http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html